# How to resolve "langinfo.h not found" error when building libiconv on OSX for Android?

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, libiconv

I try to build `libiconv` as an bibliothek accessible by an android-JNI.

I've found a lot of example makefiles to include in my Android.mk. The problem is, every time I run `ndk-build` I get the following error:

```
libiconv/libcharset/lib/localcharset.c:51:24: fatal error: langinfo.h: No such file or directory
```

I called `./configure` in the libiconv-folder but I still can't find a `langinfo.h` inside of this folder.

I am working on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. Does anybody know what to do?

**UPDATE**: There is a `langinfo.h`in `/usr/include`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same situation while I build the xbmc for android.
I just made a empty file "langinfo.h" in include directory.
And works well.

Answer (score 0):

`<langinfo.h>` is not part of Android NDK.

The `<langinfo.h>` header contains the constants used to identify items of langinfo data. You can safely copy your system header from `/usr/include` to your project's include directory to resolve the compilation error.

Note however that this could be only the first symptom. Android does not contain langinfo-compatible data at all, and provides completely different localization tools.

Comment: thx for the suggestions. I already tried to copy the langinfo.h to my include folder. This leads to further errors which I couldn't resolve so far

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find langinfo.h under `NDK_DIR/sources/android/support/include`. Make sure to include this into your include path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Modify libiconv/libcharset/config.h

comment this line 「#define HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET 1」

then ndk-build again

[image]